# Headers and cookies not working as expected <Response [403]>

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, request-headers

I am trying to access the json response on a link. It is working in my normal browser but not working when I try to access it with python requests and is sending a Cloudflare page as a response rather than json.

So far, I have tried:

1. Copying the headers from my browser and passing them to my request

```py
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Referer': 'https://9gag.com/',
    'Cookie': '____ri=5012; ____lo=US;'
}
req = requests.get("https://9gag.com/v1/group-posts/group/default/type/hot", headers=headers)
print(req)
```

2. Sending cookies seperately

```py
cookies = {
    '____ri': '5012', '____lo': 'US',
}
req = requests.get("https://9gag.com/v1/group-posts/group/default/type/hot", headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
print(req)
```

Both of these approaches are returning `<Response [403]>`